# C# Lambda Expression for iterating through nested objects

Tags: c#, json, linq, object, lambda

I have below JSON which I have de-serialized into a C# object and would like to extract the values of `INFO_CARD_ID`, `DOCUMENT_NUM` and `REVISION_NM` at each iteration.

```
{
    "result": {
        "message": "Successfully performed search",
        "columnlist": "INFO_CARD_ID,DOCUMENT_NUM,REVISION_NM,
        "recordcount": 2,
        "rows": [
            {
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "value": "UJ3P25HO3JBPLJZ2HU",
                        "key": "INFO_CARD_ID"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "DOC1",
                        "key": "DOCUMENT_NUM"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "05",
                        "key": "REVISION_NM"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "columns": [
                    {
                        "value": "JWQ5TCIV4JC2BCQ4C5",
                        "key": "INFO_CARD_ID"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "DOC2",
                        "key": "DOCUMENT_NUM"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "05",
                        "key": "REVISION_NM"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here are the C# classes:

```
    public class Columns
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rows
    {
        public IList<Columns> columns { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public string message { get; set; }
        public string columnlist { get; set; }
        public int recordcount { get; set; }
        public IList<Rows> rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class searchOutputModel
    {
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }
```

So far, I have been trying to extract the information on a list with below expression but with no luck, as the individual value is getting stored on each iteration and not all the values at each iteration at the same time.

```
searchResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<searchOutputModel>(json);

var dynamicList = searchResponse.result.rows.SelectMany(x => x.columns).Where(y => y.key.Contains("INFO_CARD_ID") || y.key.Contains("DOCUMENT_NUM") || y.key.Contains("REVISION_NM")).Select(y => {
        dynamic myValue;
        if (y.key.Contains("INFO_CARD_ID"))
            myValue = new { INFO_CARD_ID = y.value };
        else if (y.key.Contains("DOCUMENT_NUM"))
            myValue = new { DOCUMENT_NUM = y.value };
        else
            myValue = new { REVISION_NM = y.value };
        return myValue;
    }).ToList();
```

Expected output:

```
INFO_CARD_ID       DOCUMENT_NUM  REVISION_NM
---------------------------------------------
UJ3P25HO3JBPLJZ2HU DOC1          05
JWQ5TCIV4JC2BCQ4C5 DOC2          05
```

I know I am doing wrong with iteration as it creates new list at each select, but I am not sure how can I achieve the solution that I am looking for. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't use LINQ for this. Give your classes `JsonProperty` attributes so you can deserialize directly into your desired class structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to select one object per `row`, no need for `SelectMany` here. Each property can be gotten by using `columns.FirstOrDefault`.

I would advise you to create a proper class for this rather than using `dynamic` but it makes little difference to the logic below.

Not sure why you used `Contains` on the `column.key` check, I've used `==`

```cs
var dynamicList = searchResponse.result.rows.Select(r => 
    new {
        INFO_CARD_ID = r.columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.key == "INFO_CARD_ID")?.value,
        DOCUMENT_NUM = r.columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.key == "DOCUMENT_NUM")?.value,
        REVISION_NM = r.columns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.key == "REVISION_NM")?.value,
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface, this one definitely answers my question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you convert each `Rows` object to a `Dictionary`, you can use the `Dictionary` to create objects:

```
var ans = searchResponse.result.rows
            .Select(r => r.columns.ToDictionary(c => c.key, c => c.value))
            .Select(cd => new {
                INFO_CARD_ID = cd["INFO_CARD_ID"],
                DOCUMENT_NUM = cd["DOCUMENT_NUM"],
                REVISION_NM = cd["REVISION_NM"]
            });
```

Comment: Thank you @NetMage for your solution as well :)